# Can't build .NET Core projects after update

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I can't seem to find anyone with this same issue and it had me pulling out my hair for hours. I am working on a .net core project with a team of people. I realize my version was quite a bit out of date and upgraded to version 1.0.4. However, since the update, I can no longer build or run the project without errors.

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependancyResolution.targets(154,5):
>   error : Assets file
>   'C:\Users\ZL\Documents\lynx\lynx%20project\src\Lynx.Web\obj\project.assets.json'
>   not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
>   [C:\Users\ZL\Documents\lynx\lynx%20project\src\Lynx.Web\Lynx.Web.csproj]
>   obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Lynx.Web.AssembleyInfo.cs(6,12): error CS0246:
>   The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you
>   missing a directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> [C:\Users\ZL\Documents\lynx\lynx%20project\src\Lynx.Web\Lynx.Web.csproj]

These files exist and look fine. I have run a `dotnet restore` and `dotnet clean`. I tried wiping out the obj and bin folders and regenerating them. I wiped our NuGet cache. I tried uninstalling .NET Core and reinstalling it. I even blew away my code completely and pulled a fresh version from git. The other team members can build the code fine and it works on other machines just not my windows 10 machine. It seems like a dotnet restore should fix it, and everywhere I found when researching similar problems that was the fix. Some sort of version of something is out of wack but I can't figure it out. Is there something I need to update that I'm missing?

**EDITED to add csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>Lynx.Web</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>Lynx.Web</PackageId>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="node_modules\**\*" />
    <None Update="ClientApp\dist\**\*;Views\**\*;wwwroot\**\*">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="wwwroot\dist\*.map">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" Version="1.1.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="1.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" />
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a ran a NuGet package restore?

Comment: are your other team members on the same `1.0.4` version of the CLI? can you share the `.csproj` file?

Comment: @Liam when running a `nuget restore`, I receive the message "'nuget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

@MartinUllrich, I've added the csproj. The one I was speaking with last night is on v1.0.3 I believe.

Comment: and if you remove the bin / obj folders, then run `dotnet restore` again? (`dotnet`, not `nuget`)

Comment: That didn't work either. The files regenerate correctly with the restore but the project still fails to build and I get the same errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to finally figure it out. On my machine, the project was in the folder `lynx project`, however, somehow when I pulled code or updated my version that folder name changed to `lynx%20project`. Thats why it was unable to find any files. I jumped in and changed the directory name and it was fixed. Thank you all who tried to help. Hopefully this will save some poor dev some time in the future.

Comment: Poor dev just arrived, had the exact same problem. Thanks a lot!